# Oracle 2 counts

Tags: sql, oracle, count, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
create table tab_a
(
    a_child varchar2(20),
    a_parent varchar2(20)
);

create table tab_b
(
    a_child varchar2(20)
);
```

With the following data:

```
insert into tab_a values ('tom','dick snr');
insert into tab_a values ('dick jnr','dick snr');
insert into tab_a values ('harry','dick snr');

insert into tab_a values ('bob','fred');
insert into tab_a values ('ann','fred');

insert into tab_b values ('bob');
insert into tab_b values ('ann');
insert into tab_b values ('harry');
```

I would like the results to look like this:

```
a_parent | total of children in tab_a | total of children in tab_b

dick snr | 3                          | 1

fred     | 2                          | 2
```

--note: tab_a will have all the values and more that tab_b has.  In practice, tab_b is a table of archivable list of children.  However I don't want to archive any parent that hasn't got all its children in tab_b

```
  SELECT ta.a_parent, COUNT (*) AS total_child_count, (select 'x' from dual)
    FROM tab_a ta
GROUP BY ta.a_parent
```

I guess solve for x above...  Its probably a case of a join, but it needs to take a_parent into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` and an aggregation with two counts:

```
select a.a_parent, count(a.a_child) as Achildren, count(b.a_child) as Bchildren
from tab_a a left join
     tab_b b
     on a.a_child = b.a_child
group by a.a_parent;
```

If you have duplicate rows in the tables, then you should use `count(distinct)` instead of `count()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and xQbert.  Answered almost too fast :) I had to wait to click mark as answer. And Matt.